# How do I emulate a computed property with access to the latest value in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

If I want to emulate a standard property of e.g a `Bool` in RxSwift I can use `let isValid = Variable<Bool>(false)` and then use `.value` to get the last value inline and `.asObservable()` to access the stream.

However I want to emulate a computed propery e.g. `var isValid { return self.password.characters.count > 0 }` and also be able to get the last value inline as well as in the form of an observable stream.

I want to be able to do both so I can write code like ...

```
if isValid.value { // isValid is Variable<Bool>
    // ... do something ....
}
```

as well as bind to e.g. a TextField

I know I can write as a pure `Observable`  as follows ...

```
var isValid: Observable<Bool> {
    return self.username.asObservable().map { username in   // username is Variable<String>
        return username.characters.count > 0
    }
}
```

but then I have to refactor the previous example to be ....

```
isValid.subscribe { isValid in 
    if isValid.element {
        // ... do something ....
    }
}.dispose(of: self.disposeBag)
```

How then do I express a computed property in RxSwift which can be consumed as an inline value as well as a stream?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up with a solution that does not look clean but works. I would add a new `var valid: Bool = false` and a subscription to the `isValid` observable that updates it

isValid.subscribe(onNext:{ [weak self] value in self?.valid = valid})

With this `isValid` is used for binding and subscriptions and `valid` for use in imperative code.

Btw your definition of `isValid` is kind of "unnatural", just make it a `let isValid: Observable<Bool>` and assign it in `init` like `isValid = username.asObservable().map({$0.characters.count > 0})`

Update:

Another solution is using RxBlockling, you can get the current value with `try! isValid.toBlocking().single()` but I think it is a worse solution and generally not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let username = Variable("")

private let _isValid: Observable<Bool> = username.asObservable().map{ $0.characters.count > 0 }

let isValid = Variable(false)
```

Then, in your `init`, `viewDidLoad`or wherever:

```
_isValid.asObservable()
    .bind(to: isValid)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

You can test it with:

```
isValid.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print("value: \($0)")

    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

username.value = "xfreire"

// OUTPUTS:
// value: false
// value: true
```

and you are still able to do:

```
if isValid.value {
    // ...
}
```